# No badge for receiving bounty

Tags: discussion, answers, bounty

I'm wondering why we have 4 badges for offering a bounty and no one for receiving it. They looks kinda similar for me.

Please, describe the difference between them.

Comment: Isn't the bonus for receiving a bounty the bounty itself? The point of getting badges for placing bounties is that you don't get anything else for placing a bounty

Comment: As for me, badges acknowledge your significant actions and engage you to participate on this site more actively. By your logic half of existing badges should be deleted, because they have other benefits

Comment: @Ossir You could have a case if you wanted to make a feature-request for a badge after so many bounties or something similar. But the answer badges don't reward simply an answer but an answer that (typically) shows effort and detail. This encourages people to post well thought out and helpful answers which , in turn, will help the community.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By *receiving* a bounty you're not doing anything positive for the community that isn't already being rewarded. You've answered the question and are eligible for all the answer badges and you've got a bounty, which means a reputation boost.

The bounty badges are there to introduce people to the functionality and to get people helping others by putting bounties on someone else's question. In receiving a bounty you're not learning anything about the functionality of the site and you've got your reward already.